# Use multiple dropdowns with the same Js function

Tags: javascript, html

I have this column where I am supposed to display products

Right now the 1st dropdown only opens I want the user to able to open all of them in order to see all products

I am using the standard pure Js dropdown model

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Products1 or 2</button>
  
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <img src="images/E11A.png" class="bottles" />
    <img src="images/E11A.png" class="bottles" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot have multiple elements with the same ID, ID has to be unique. aka `myDropdown`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment you can't have multiple elements with the same name.

So what we could do given the html you have provided, is add `this` to `onclick="myFunction()"` and then do the following:

```
function myFunction(obj) {
  obj.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

**Working Demo**

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction(obj) {
  obj.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: grey;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: url('g50.png');
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1080px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.a {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.dropbtn {
  width: 98%;
  padding: 14px;
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
  display: none;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <img src="images/E11A.png" class="bottles" />
        <img src="images/E11A.png" class="bottles" />
      </div>

      <div class="dropdown">
        <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <img src="images/E11A.png" class="bottles" />
          <img src="images/E11A.png" class="bottles" />
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not be using the same id twice try using a class instead, e.g.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
<div class="myDropdown dropdown-content">
  <img src="images/E11A.png" class="bottles"/>
  <img src="images/E11A.png" class="bottles"/>
</div>
```

Then in your javascript you can simply write the following to open both dropdowns

```
function myFunction() {
  document.querySelectorAll("myDropdown").forEach(el => el.classList.toggle("show"));
}
```